# Anguar2 routerLink returning inaccurate URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-services, typescript2.0

I am trying to implement angular2 routers and by using the URL pattern like '/detail/:index' to pass something like ':detail/1234' . but it's getting "someDomain/detail/%3AitemIndex;itemIndex=123" which means "/detail/:itemIndex;itemIndex=123". How to fix this and get the expected result which is "/detail/123" OR "/detail/itemIndex=123" and get rid of that ":itemIndex;" and replace it with slash (Please ignore my typos)

"app.routes.ts"

```
 export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'SomeHomeComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: SomeHomeComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:itemIndex', component: SomeDetailComponent }];
```

"list.component.html"

```
  <a *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
[routerLink]="['/detail/:itemIndex', { itemIndex: i }]"> 
{ item.name }
</a>
```

"SomeDetail.Component.ts"

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class SomeDetailComponent {
  private itemIndex:string;

  constructor(private  route: ActivatedRoute){

  }
  ngOnInit () {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.itemIndex = params['itemIndex'];
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use :

"list.component.html"

```
<a *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
    [routerLink]="['/detail', i]"> 
    {{ item.name }}
</a>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html) documentation, you can concatenate multiple variable with multiple parameter.

Your code would now become:

```
<a *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [routerLink]="['/detail/', i ]"> 
    {{ item.name }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

PS: just suggestion

better to use `elvis ?` operator when binding using *ngFor or something like that, it prevents error or crash of app like this,

```
 <a *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
[routerLink]="['/detail/:itemIndex', { itemIndex: i }]"> 
{{ item?.name }}
</a>
```

here i have used `{{item?.name}}`